# Jenkins use different stages for different apps

Tags: jenkins, deployment, jenkins-pipeline, stage

I have different apps in different projects. In dev project are together, but separate in the others. Like this:

```
dev project -> app1, app2
tst_intranet project -> app1
tst_internet project -> app2
```

Now my stages contains all the stages for both apps.

```
pipeline { 
agent any

stages{
 stage('Init which app is app1, and app2)
 stage('Parameter initialization for app1')
 stage('Deploy for app1')
 stage('Parameter initialization for app2')
 stage('Deploy for app2')
 }
}
```

But, I want to to run all stages, when I deploy for dev, but if I deploy for tst_intranet project, I want to run only "for app1" stages, or "for app2" stages, when I deploy for tst_internet.

Thanks for your helping.

Comment: use [when](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when)

Answer (score 1):

As Vasiliy Ratanov mentioned you can use when directive to conditionally run your stages. In your case something like below.

```
pipeline { 
agent any

stages{
 stage('Init which app is app1, and app2)
 stage('Parameter initialization for app1') {
     when { expression { environment == "dev" ||  environment == "tst_intranet"  } }
     steps{}
 }
 stage('Deploy for app1') {
     when { expression { environment == "dev" ||  environment == "tst_intranet"  } }
     steps{}
 }
 stage('Parameter initialization for app2') {
     when { expression { environment == "dev" ||  environment == "tst_internet"  } }
     steps{}
 }
 stage('Deploy for app2') {
     when { expression { environment == "dev" ||  environment == "tst_internet"  } }
     steps{}
 }
 }
}
```